# Partly mirrored p2 repository does not contain installable units - "There are no items available" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tycho, p2, mirror

I want to mirror some features from the latest Orbit update site. I use the configuraiton below. (This configuration is taken it from the effective pom, to make sure that this is really the configuration I used.)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.18.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>mirror-orbit-R20130827064939</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>mirror</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    <repository>
                        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130827064939/repository</url>
                        <layout>p2</layout>
                    </repository>
                </source>
                <ius>
                    <iu><id>com.google.guava</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>com.google.guava.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.mockito</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.mockito.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.junit</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.junit.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.objenesis</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.objenesis.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.core</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.core.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.text</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.text.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.library</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.library.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.integration</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.integration.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.generator</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.hamcrest.generator.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.slf4j.log4j</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.slf4j.log4j.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.slf4j.api</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>org.slf4j.api.source</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>javax.servlet</id></iu>
                    <iu><id>javax.servlet.source</id>
                </ius>
                <destination>/somefolder/mirror/orbit/R20130827064939</destination>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I build the maven pom, and the mirrored repository seems to be ok:

```
R20130827064939
-plugins
--com.google.guava_12.0.0.v201212092141.jar
--com.google.guava_12.0.0.v201212092141.jar.pack.gz
--com.google.guava.source_12.0.0.v201212092141.jar
--com.google.guava.source_12.0.0.v201212092141.jar.pack.gz
--com.thoughtworks.qdox_1.6.3.v20081201-1400.jar
--com.thoughtworks.qdox_1.6.3.v20081201-1400.jar.pack.gz
--javax.annotation_1.0.0.v201209060030.jar
--javax.annotation_1.0.0.v201209060030.jar.pack.gz
--javax.annotation_1.1.0.v201209060031.jar
--javax.annotation_1.1.0.v201209060031.jar.pack.gz
--javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar
--javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar.pack.gz
--javax.servlet.source_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar
--javax.servlet.source_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar.pack.gz
--javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar
--javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v201303080311.jar
--org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v201303080311.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201303080312.jar
--org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201303080312.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030.jar
--org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.batik.css_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar
--org.apache.batik.css_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.batik.dom_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar
--org.apache.batik.dom_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.batik.util_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar
--org.apache.batik.util_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.7.0.v200903091627.jar
--org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.7.0.v200903091627.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.batik.xml_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar
--org.apache.batik.xml_1.7.0.v201011041433.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.xerces_2.8.0.v200803070308.jar
--org.apache.xerces_2.8.0.v200803070308.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.xml.resolver_1.1.0.v200806030311.jar
--org.apache.xml.resolver_1.1.0.v200806030311.jar.pack.gz
--org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0.v201005080400.jar
--org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0.v201005080400.jar.pack.gz
--org.easymock_2.4.0.v20090202-0900.jar
--org.easymock_2.4.0.v20090202-0900.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
--org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.core.source_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar
--org.hamcrest.core.source_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.generator_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.generator_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.generator.source_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.generator.source_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.integration_1.1.0.v201303031500.jar
--org.hamcrest.integration_1.1.0.v201303031500.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.integration.source_1.1.0.v201303031500.jar
--org.hamcrest.integration.source_1.1.0.v201303031500.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.library_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.library_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.library.source_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.library.source_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.text_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.text_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.hamcrest.text.source_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar
--org.hamcrest.text.source_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20130308-0410.jar
--org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20130308-0410.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20130308-0414.jar
--org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20130308-0414.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar
--org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit_4.7.0.v4_7_0_v20130308-0411.jar
--org.junit_4.7.0.v4_7_0_v20130308-0411.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20130308-0412.jar
--org.junit_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20130308-0412.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20130308-0413.jar
--org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20130308-0413.jar.pack.gz
--org.junit.source_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar
--org.junit.source_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar.pack.gz
--org.mockito_1.8.4.v201303031500.jar
--org.mockito_1.8.4.v201303031500.jar.pack.gz
--org.mockito.source_1.8.4.v201303031500.jar
--org.mockito.source_1.8.4.v201303031500.jar.pack.gz
--org.objenesis_1.0.0.v201105211943.jar
--org.objenesis_1.0.0.v201105211943.jar.pack.gz
--org.objenesis.source_1.0.0.v201105211943.jar
--org.objenesis.source_1.0.0.v201105211943.jar.pack.gz
--org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar
--org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar.pack.gz
--org.slf4j.api.source_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar
--org.slf4j.api.source_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar.pack.gz
--org.slf4j.log4j_1.7.2.v20130115-1340.jar
--org.slf4j.log4j_1.7.2.v20130115-1340.jar.pack.gz
--org.slf4j.log4j.source_1.7.2.v20130115-1340.jar
--org.slf4j.log4j.source_1.7.2.v20130115-1340.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.v200805290154.jar
--org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.v200805290154.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar
--org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.1.v200903091627.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.dom.events_3.0.0.draft20060413_v201105210656.jar
--org.w3c.dom.events_3.0.0.draft20060413_v201105210656.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011.jar
--org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar
--org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.1.v200903091627.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar.pack.gz
--org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar
-artifacts.jar
-contents.jar
```

However when I load it into a target file specification in Eclipse, it says that there is nothing to choose from:
[image]

If I remove the `<ius>` tag (and hence disable the filtering), Eclipse still shows it as empty. So full mirroring also does not work.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository contains only plug-ins that's why you have nothing in Install dialog. The resulting repository itself is correct and can be used in builds to resolve dependencies.

To have all plugins visible in Install dialog you cold consider mirroring org.eclipse.orbit.category.all category IU.

Another option to consider is building p2 repository using packaging (this is just a guess and I haven't tested it):

```
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
```

and category.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <bundle id="com.google.guava" version="0.0.0">
       <category name="all"/>
   </bundle>
   <bundle id="com.google.guava.source" version="0.0.0">
       <category name="all"/>
   </bundle>

   <category-def name="all" label="My Orbit bundles"/>
</site>
```

Comment: How should I do it? Can tycho do it?

Comment: If you take a look at the zipped orbit update site at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20130827064939/orbit-buildrepo-R20130827064939.zip it also does not have any features folder content.

Comment: I was wrong, those IU ids in your configuration are features. Does unselect "Show only the latest version" help?

Comment: where do you see a feature?

Comment: Good point, I really don't see any features. This repo contains categories which are just meta IUs without artifact and plugin IU grouped under several categories. To mirror that properly you need to mirror categories not plug-ins. I've just tested snipped from question with <ius><iu><id>org.eclipse.orbit.category.tests</id></iu></ius> and it works as Gábor expected.

Comment: @GáborLipták: Your comment should be a comment... ;-)

Comment: It seems, that categories containing plugins are not mirrored automatically in case of a full mirroring (if you do not define any installable unit). However as stated here, if you mirror the org.eclipse.orbit.category.all, then all plugins in the category will be mirrorred. There seem to be no way to filter however the plugins to be mirrored from the category. So in this case the only way for me to get some of the plugins to build a new p2 site using Orbit as a dependency.

Comment: @oberlies: Here it is :) Any comment on my comment? Am I right with it?